# 「猫種」「愛猫」などの読み方について

Tags: readings

「愛犬」は「アイケン」と音読みで読みます。
「犬種」も「ケンシュ」と音読みです。

さて、猫の場合はどうでしょうか。

「猫」という字は音で読むと「ビョウ」ですので、正しくは「アイビョウ」「ビョウシュ」ではないでしょうか。

しかし「アイビョウが・・・」って言われてすぐにピンとくる人がどれほどいるのか疑問です。

ネットで調べたら、わかりやすさを優先し「あいねこ」「ねこしゅ」と読むようにしているという人も少なくないようです。

そこでお聞きしたいのですが、「愛猫」「猫種」の正しい読み方は何ですか？そして、日常会話では普段どのように発音されていますか？それとも、会話ではそういった言葉を避けて「ペットの猫」「猫の種類」などと言い換えたりするのが普通ですか？

さっき読んでいた本で「猫種」が出てきてちょっと気になったのでご教示いただければ幸いです。

> [...] 雪ノ下は、雑誌の耳を丁寧に折る。いわゆるドッグイヤーというやつだ。猫好き雪ノ下なら、「これは犬の耳ではなくスコティッシュフォールドの耳よ」などと言い出すかもしれない。ちなみに、スコティッシュフォールドは猫にしては珍しく、それこそドッグイヤーのような折れた耳が特徴的で人気のある**猫種**だ。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

詳しくは[ネットのアンケートの結果](http://news.mynavi.jp/news/2014/06/25/115/)に書かれているようなので、私個人の経験と印象だけ書きます。たまに[猫カフェ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8C%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7)には行きますが、猫を飼ったことはありません。

「愛猫」に関しては、正しい読みが「あいびょう」だと知っており、すんなりとそう読めました。他の読み方をしてしまうと、個人的にはちょっと恥ずかしいと思います。ただし難しい表現なので、会話では「好きな猫」などと言い換えます。

「猫種」に関しては、そもそもこの単語をほとんど見た記憶がありません。読めと言われると、おそらく少し悩んでから「びょうしゅ」と読むと思いますが、実際には「ねこしゅ」もよく使われているようです。

Answer (score 2):

This is my personal opinion.
That word is rarely used and not on a dictionary I checked. So, I think there is no correct answer to this.
I would 湯桶読みして「ねこしゅ」, and I would use 猫の種類 instead in conversations.

Japanese has a lot of 同音異義語, so sometimes words are read in a different way to avoid confusion.
http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/~ts/language/homophone.html

Comment: せっかく頑張って日本語で質問されているのに・・・

Comment: Sorry, I don't write Japanese in my daily life :-(.